# How to fill NaN based on groupby transform without loosing the column grouped by?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset containing heights, weights etc, and I intend to fill the NaN values with the mean value for that gender.

Example dataset:

```
    gender    height    weight
1     M          5       NaN
2     F          4       NaN
3     F         NaN        40
4     M         NaN        50
```

```
df = df.groupby("Gender").transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

current output:

```
     height    weight
1       5        50
2       4        40
3       4        40
4       5        50
```

Expected output:

```
    gender    height    weight
1     M          5        50
2     F          4        40
3     F          4        40
4     M          5        50
```

Unfortunately this drops the column Gender which is important later on.

Comment: Please share a sample of your dataframe with expected output.

Comment: `groupby` put the group labels as index, if you don't want this, you need to specify `as_index=False`.

Comment: @MayankPorwal updated original question.

Comment: @ashkangh that ends up giving me value error as a column I have contains strings.

Comment: how do you do `df['data'].groupby(["Gender"])`???

Comment: my apologies, it should be df['data'].groupby('Gender')

Comment: @Blaine Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about looping through the 2 columns you want to fill, and perform `GroupBy.transform`, grouping by 'gender':

```
for col in ['height','weight']:
    df[col] = df.groupby('gender')[col].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))

print(df)

  gender  height  weight
0      M     5.0    50.0
1      F     4.0    40.0
2      F     4.0    40.0
3      M     5.0    50.0
```

If you want to fill all the numerical columns, you can get them in a `list`, and perform the same approach:

```
features_to_impute = [
        x for x in df.columns if df[x].dtypes != 'O' and df[x].isnull().mean() > 0
        ]

for col in features_to_impute:
    df[col] = df.groupby('gender')[col].transform(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: This makes sense, but what if I also needed to do this for all columns with NaNs?

Comment: I have addressed your question in the edited answer. Let me know if it works

Comment: shouldn't it be for col in features_to_impute: ?

Comment: I think it works both ways. I was thinking that too. Try it if you can on your dataset and I'll edit it

Comment: Additionally instead of running a for loop I think you can just do df[features_to_impute] = df.groupby('gender')features_to_impute] .....

Comment: Yes, could do that too.

Comment: Thanks! You can update your original answer for further reference if you so desire.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using groupby, you can reach your expected output like below:

```
 df = df.groupby('gender').apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x.mean()))
```

Comment: but this doesnt fill mean based on gender

Comment: So I think he can specify what columns to assign with the above answer.

Comment: There is an additional Gender column in this case, anyway to resolve this? So I can add a group by further down as well?

Comment: it's simple:
`groupby("gender", as_index=False)`